# How Can I filtered a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a weird problem. I'm trying to block a dataframe from being processed when it has a NaN value for a specific column(in this case, "name").

```
print(df)
   Assets_%  Code  Country  Exchange  Industry  Name  Region  Sector
0     100.0   NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN
```

I've been trying different things but this row keeps sneaking past my filters:

```
if pd.notna(df['Name'].any):
  #do something
elif df['Name'].isnull().any:
  print("There is has a null value in name")
```

for some reason, the above data makes it through. What can I do? Is notna the right way to catch NaN values?

Comment: Why not simply `df[~df.Name.isna()]` ?

Comment: `any` is a method, not a property, you need to call: `if df['Name'].isna().any():`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **.any()** with parenthesis otherwise df['Name'].any will just return the method but not the boolean value.